# why user state is deleted after the page refresh

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

I created a user state with redux toolkit. Everything works fine when the user is logged in. The userActions sends a request to backend and returns the user info as token and username to display it on the navbar. The problem is the user state is returned to initial state after the page refresh. Is it a good idea to use useEffect to send a request to backend after each rerender which is not a good idea or to use the cache?

I tried to use RTK query to cash the user state but is it secure?

Comment: Redux will not persist state by default, so the refresh will clear your cache regardless of rtk-query. Please update your question with better description of your issue and add some code snippets, so that it is better possible to answer

Comment: i know that the state is not a memory so it must be cleared with a refresh but is it secure to use the localstorage to store the user info ???

Comment: React state and Redux stores, exist only in memory, so when the page is reloaded anything stored in memory on the previous "instance" is dumped. Please [edit] your post to be more focused and objective. If necessary, please also include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with that you need help improving or resolving a problem of.

Answer (score 3):

That's a normal behaviour, state is being reset on refresh per specification. If you want to preserve it you need to make use of localStorage/sessionStorage/cookies etc.

Comment: is it really a good idea to store the user info in local storage??

Comment: @AhmedBousaleh Yeah it is good practice and you need to store the data, (that will be used throughout a session like user data) in any of the mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

That's where `cookies` come into play. You can save the user details in `cookies` for that session. It is good practice to maintain user details in `cookies` and data in the `cookies` can be accessed by both client side and the server side.